# Unterschied zwischen jemandem Möglichkeiten bieten und einräumen

Tags: difference

Welcher ist der Unterschied zwischen den Ausdrücken

> jm. Möglichkeit(en) bieten

und

> jm. Möglichkeit(en) einräumen

Und gibt es überhaupt welchen?

Comment: Etwas mehr Kontext wäre hilfreich.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wenn wir (1) mit (2) vergleichen, ändert das Wort ‚Möglichkeit‘ seine Bedeutung.

(1) jemandem (eine) Möglichkeit(en) bieten

(2) jemandem (eine) Möglichkeit(en) einräumen

In (1) heißt ‚Möglichkeit‘ so viel wie ‚Chance‘ oder ‚Gelegenheit‘. In (2) heißt ‚Möglichkeit‘ eher ‚Alternative‘ oder ‚möglicher Verlauf‘. Das folgende Satzpaar mag dies verdeutlichen.

(1a) Der Verlagsleiter bot Peter die Möglichkeit (an), eng mit dem berühmten Autor Hans Müller zusammenzuarbeiten.

(2a) Der Staatsanwalt räumte die Möglichkeit ein, daß der Angeklagte zur Tatzeit nicht am Tatort war.

In (1a) erhält Peter eine Chance. In (2a) gibt der Staatsanwalt zu, daß es so-und-so gewesen sein könnte. (Könnte = Möglichkeit) Wir könnten auch sagen: ‚Er räumte es *als* Möglichkeit ein‘.

In (2a) könne wir ‚einräumen‘ nicht mit ‚anbieten‘ ersetzen. Ob ‚anbieten‘ in (1a) durch ‚einräumen‘ ersetzt werden kann, ist nicht ganz klar. Vielleicht wollte der Verlagsleiter eigentlich gar nicht, daß Peter mit Hans Müller zusammenarbeitet. Dann könnte man *evtl.* ‚einräumen‘ benützen, aber ich finde es nicht sehr gelungen. Besser wäre es, einfach das Wort ‚widerwillig‘ hinzuzufügen: ‚Widerwillig bot der Verlagsleiter Peter die Möglichkeit an, …‘

Zuletzt fällt noch auf, daß wir ‚Möglichkeit(en)‘ als Subjekt benützen können:

(1b) Ihm bot sich eine neue Möglichkeit.

(1c) Eine andere Möglichkeit hat sich uns damals nicht geboten.

Die folgenden Sätze sind hingegen unsinnig:

(2b) #Ihm räumte sich eine neue Möglichkeit ein.

(2c) #Eine andere Möglichkeit hat sich uns damals nicht eingeräumt.

Comment: Der Unterschied zwischen (1a) und (2a) ist sehr gelungen dargestellt. Allerdings entspricht (2a) nicht dem *(2) **jemandem** (eine) Möglichkeit einräumen*

Comment: @Min-Soo Pipefeet Ich glaube schon, daß (2a) und (2) einander entsprechen. Ich hätte doch schreiben können: ‚Der Staatsanwalt räumte **dem Verteidiger** die Möglichkeit ein …‘. Das klingt vielleicht ein Wenig steif (weshalb ich es auch weggelassen hatte); aber natürlich kann ‚einräumen‘ hier – wie sonst auch – mit Dativobjekt auftreten. (Andernfalls wäre ja (2) von vornherein falsch, oder?)

Comment: Ja, das hättest Du zwar schreiben können, aber richtig klingt das für mich nicht. Das wäre äquivalent zu "Es wäre **dem Verteidiger** möglich, dass der Angeklagte zur Tatzeit nicht am Tatort war" - das ergibt keinen Sinn, denn die Möglichkeit bezieht sich auf den Angeklagten und ist **an sich** existent - für alle. Man kann **jemandem** ein *Recht* oder eine *Kreditlinie* einräumen, aber keine Möglichkeit. Man kann höchstens **jemandem** *zugestehen*, **dass** es die Möglichkeit gibt, dass ... - Aber das ist wiederum ne andere Sache.

Comment: Zu: "Andernfalls wäre ja (2) von vornherein falsch, oder?" - Nein, siehe zum Beispiel den Satz: "Die Mitgliedstaaten können der zuständigen Behörde jedoch die Möglichkeit einräumen, die Frist des Unterabsatzes 1 zu verkürzen." Ein authentischer und korrekter Satz. Ist nicht weit von "Möglichkeit bieten", aber nicht ganz. Könnte vielleicht Schlüssel zur Antwort auf die Frage sein.

Comment: @Min-Soo Pipefeet Meines Erachtens kann ‚Er räumte ihm die Möglichkeit ein, daß …‘ verstanden werden kann als ‚Er gestand ihm zu, daß…‘ bzw. als ‚Er räumte ihm ein, daß es möglich ist, daß …‘ (Früher konnte man auch sagen: ‚Er gab **ihm** zu, daß…‘.)

Comment: Es mag vielleicht regionale Unterschiede oder Eigenheiten geben. Ich will nicht sagen, dass es ultimativ falsch ist, denn Grammatik bzw. Sprachregeln sind immer nur deskriptiv/beschreibend - und vielleicht spricht ja jemand wirklich so. Ich sage lediglich, dass es sich **für mich** falsch anhört. Genauer: "Er räumte ihm die Möglichkeit ein, dass ..." -> hört sich falsch an; selbst bei wohlwollender Interpretation wüsste ich nicht, was die Dativ-Einfügung bedeuten soll; dagegen hört sich "Er räumte ihm die Möglichkeit ein, etwas zu tun" für mich richtig an, und hier ergibt der Dativ einen Sinn.

Comment: Chancen und Gelegenheiten kann man also bieten, aber nicht einräumen; Alternativen oder mögliche Verläufe einräumen, aber nicht bieten? Nicht plausibel.

Answer (score 0):

In den meisten Fällen sind beide Wörter austauschbar.
**Bieten** bedeutet eher ein aktives Anbieten.
**Einräumen** bedeutet eher ein passives Erlauben

Comment: Die Unterscheidung aktiv/passiv trifft es nicht. Was soll das sein, passives Erlauben? Dann wäre _einräumen_ ja auch passiv, ist es aber auch nicht.

Comment: Vielleicht trifft es das Gegensatzpaar offensiv/defensiv besser. Ich kann mir schon ungefähr vorstellen, worauf die Antwort hinaus will, ein bisschen mehr Erklärung würde ihr allerdings sicher nicht schaden.

Comment: Aktiv/passiv ist möglicherweise falsch ausgedrückt: Meinst du "freudig zustimmend" vs. "unwillig nachgebend" (was beides "aktiv" ist)?

Answer (score 0):

Obwohl es bereits eine akzeptierte Antwort gibt, möchte ich nochmal auf einen anderen Aspekt des Unterschieds hinaus, der sich tatsächlich auf das verwendete Verb selbst bezieht.

Wenn ich jemandem eine Möglichkeit (an)biete, dann existiert diese Möglichkeit bereits, und ich biete ihm die bestehende Möglichkeit an.

Wenn ich jemandem eine Möglichkeit einräume, dann SCHAFFE ich die Möglichkeit erst, bevor ich Sie dem anderen anbiete.

Vergleiche:

Ich biete Dir die Möglichkeit, für mich als Teamleiter zu arbeiten:

Die Stelle des "Teamleiters" existiert bereits, ich biete sie dem Gegenüber an.

Ich räume Dir die Möglichkeit ein, für mich als Teamleiter zu arbeiten:

Ich schaffe die Stelle des "Teamleiters" und biete sie dem Gegenüber an.

Comment: Ich biete dir die Möglichkeit, eine neu zu schaffende Stelle als mein Teamleiter zu besetzen. Ich räume dir die Möglichkeit ein, die Stelle mit meinem bisherigen Teamleiter zu tauschen. Geht beides, oder?